# Why is my Neo4J merge query slow when creating new records?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4J Desktop with database version 3.5.6.

When I run the query below on an empty database and about 775,000 records in the CSV it takes about 90 seconds. If I run it again it takes about 25 seconds. Is this typical? I expected really fast performance from Neo4J. I do have indexes and constraints, so the query plan starts with a NodeUniqueIndexSeek. Is there a better way to write the query?

```
using periodic commit
load csv  with headers from file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/graphene_dev/csv/bugs.csv' as line
merge (n:Bug {id: line.id})
    set n.id = line.id,
    n.title = line.title,
    n.status = line.status,
    n.status_reason = line.status_reason,
    n.submitted_by = line.submitted_by, 
    n.owner = line.owner,
    n.submitted_date = line.submitted_date;
```

These are the Java settings I have changed

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the nodes already exist, your query would still set their properties. That may not be what you intended (and would, of course, take some time).

If you only want your query to set the properties of nodes that are newly-created by `MERGE`, then you should use the [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/merge/#query-merge-on-create-on-match) clause, as in:

```
using periodic commit
load csv with headers from file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/graphene_dev/csv/bugs.csv' as line
merge (n:Bug {id: line.id})
on create set
    n.title = line.title,
    n.status = line.status,
    n.status_reason = line.status_reason,
    n.submitted_by = line.submitted_by, 
    n.owner = line.owner,
    n.submitted_date = line.submitted_date;
```

This query should be much faster the second time it is run, especially since you have an index on `:Bug(id)`.

*By the way, my query's `set` clause omits the redundant `n.id = line.id` assignment, since the `merge` clause already guarantees that `n.id` is equal to `line.id`.*

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome. I can also use on match set to set any fields that might change